# Can't Log In to Visual Studio 2015 - System.Net.Http.Primitives not loaded

Tags: visual-studio

My license for VS Community 2015 went stale.  Now any attempt to sign in or update my license leads to an error message of "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."  I ran `devenv /log` and have traced the issue to a "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0...'" exception that gets thrown when VS tries to authenticate or something.

I have tried repairing and then reinstalling VStudio, including running the "scorch" uninstall tool in Github.
I tried running `sfc /scannow` and it found no integrity violations.  Everything I find online related to this exception tells me how to fix it for a project running in VS, but not how to fix it when VS itself throws it.
I tried `devenv /resetuserdata` and `/ResetSettings`.  Nothing has worked.

I feel like I need to update my GAC manually from a trusted DLL, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to do that.

This is the full XML log entry element where the error occurs from `devenv /log`:

```
<entry>
<record>368</record>
<time>2016/12/13 17:21:54.787</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>UserConnection</source>
<description>User:IdeUser, Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.: TargetInvocationException [inner: Could not load file or assembly &apos;System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.] during ExplicitSignIn&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.VssConnection.&lt;GetClientInstanceAsync&gt;d__15.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.VssConnection.&lt;GetClientServiceImplAsync&gt;d__13.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.VssConnection.&lt;GetClientAsync&gt;d__10`1.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.VssServerDataProvider.&lt;ConnectAsync&gt;d__39.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.IdeConnector.&lt;ConnectAsync&gt;d__2.MoveNext() (ActivityId: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)</description>
```

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Hi, I voted to move on superuser, as for me your question would be a better fit there, than there for server related's issue.

Comment: ok, is there a way I can do that myself?  Just delete and recreate?  Sucks to get downvoted :(

Comment: Flag a moderator is the best way :)

Comment: Probably belongs on stackoverflow

Comment: @JimB - It does not.

Comment: What Visual Studio 2015 Update do you have installed if any?  You should try: `Devenv.exe /ResetSettings` instead of the command you issued.  `devenv /resetuserdatas` isn't a valid command, its suppose to be, `devenv /resetuserdata`

Comment: You can also delete the contents within the following folder: `LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache\\`

Comment: Of course even if you get rid of the invalid license, this won't allow you to retrieve a valid license, your current configuration is blocking communication to the Microsoft server.